# Get Calendar Items in Exchange

Tags: c#, list, generics, sharepoint, exchangewebservices

I have a little problem with my Sharepoint 2 Exchange Tool. Maybe sb from you can help me here :)

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(m_Office365URL))
        {


            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in m_password.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
            SharePointOnlineCredentials xCred = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(m_userName, passWord);
            clientContext.Credentials = xCred;
            Web xWeb = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(xWeb);
            clientContext.Load(clientContext.Site.RootWeb);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            DateTime calDate = startDate;
            List targetList = xWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(m_TargetListName);
            clientContext.Load(targetList);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This is fully working an haven't any error inside.
Now my thing is to get this as similar as possible working for Exchange.

Here's what I have until now:

```
ExchangeService m_Service = new ExchangeService(m_Url);
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in m_Password.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
            m_Service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(m_UserName, m_Password);

            foreach (Appointment appointment in m_Service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new ItemView(int.MaxValue)))
            { 
                DateTime calDate = startDate;

                ExchangeService xWeb = m_Service;                             
                m_Service.UpdateItems(xWeb);                             
                m_Service.Load(m_Service.Site.RootWeb);                             
                m_Service.ExecuteQuery();                             

                List targetList = xWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(m_TargetListName);                             
                m_Service.Load(targetList);                             
                m_Service.ExecuteQuery();
```

But As you can guess I get Poblems startin at "`ExchangeService xWeb = new m_Service`" 
For sure the m_Service.UpdateItems, m_Service.Load etc won't work either.

If somebody might have a hint for me that'd be great.

Comment: Hi Unlockedluca, Are you trying to move calendar data from SharePoint to Exchange?  Have you taken a look at Exchange 101 Code samples (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exchange/Exchange-2013-101-Code-3c38582c) to see how to do this.  Not sure about your scenario and hence posting this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Hi @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT So kind for you looking into my problem, I'll have a look in the CodeSamples, I've heard of them once but actually they've gotten out of my mind while coding ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run this code using:

```
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Ise_ExchangeInterface.CertificateValidationCallBack;
            m_Service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
            m_Service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(m_UserName, m_Password);
            m_Service.AutodiscoverUrl(m_UserName, Ise_ExchangeInterface.RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```